# HhttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to get the ID of the user who made a request to the GetUser endpoint, but the claims always return null. What am I missing?

```
  [ApiController]
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {
     public LoginController (IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
     {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
     }

    [HttpGet("GetUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser()
    {
       
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        return user; // user claims is always null
    }
}
```

[image]

Startup.cs

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
     ...
     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();,
     ...
     }
```

DbContext

```
public class TestAppContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

       optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("", npgsqlOptions =>
        {
        });
    }
    ...
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the `Request.HttpContect` object?

Comment: i have no reason but how do I get current user with Request.Httpcontext ?

Comment: Where are you setting the user? What is your authentication middleware configuration?

Comment: user information will be available only after authentication.

Comment: Does your user log in? You couldn't access it if the user doesn't authenticate. Please have a look at the [official document for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0).